# Flickering menu when hover over dropdown

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, menu, responsive, flicker

I've been working on a website for a while and had no trouble with the menu then one day, my menu started flickering like crazy when we hover over it.

What causes the flickering of the menu when we hover over it?

I am not able to click on the sub-menu items because it flickers then it disappears.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stack overflow. Please see the help center https://stackoverflow.com/help in order to ask a proper question. At the least we would need a minimal, viable example of your problem in code! Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem in the code is... that's my question.

Comment: we mean is that you have to **show** the code so we can find the problem.

Comment: Here's my menusm.js code

Comment: .menu { margin:0px 0 0 0; width:  auto; padding:0; text-transform:uppercase; font-size:13px; font-weight:normal; float:right; }
.menu_wrap {border-left: 1px solid #3333ff; border-right: 1px solid #3333ff;}
/* level 0 */

.menu ul.sf-menu { padding:0; margin:0 auto; width: 620px;  }

@media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  .menu ul.sf-menu{width: 620px;}
}
list-style-type: none;
noindex:-o-prefocus, .menu ul.menusm {
 width: 620px;
}

Comment: /*//active*/
.menu ul li#active_menu-nav a.ms_top,
.menu ul li a.ms_top.ms_hover,
.menu ul li.active a.ms_top,
.menu ul li a.ms_top.ms_hover span,
.menu ul li.active a.ms_top span { color:#cc0000; text-decoration:none; /*background:url(../images/menu_a.png) repeat-x top center;/**/  }

.menu ul li a.ms_top.ms_hover,
.menu ul li.active a.ms_top { border-top:4px solid #961309; }

/*/////////////////////buttons*/

Comment: .menu ul li a.ms_top.ms_havesubmenu span {/*background:url(../images/menu_r_d.png) no-repeat right top;/**/ }
.menu ul li.active a.ms_top.ms_havesubmenu span {/*background:url(../images/menu_r_da.png) no-repeat right top;/**/ }
.menu ul li a.ms_top.ms_havesubmenu.ms_hover span {/*background:url(../images/menu_r_da.png) no-repeat right top;/**/ }
.menu ul li a.active,
.menu ul li a.ms_hover,
.menu ul li a.ms_havesubmenu.active,
.menu ul li a.ms_havesubmenu.ms_hover {/*background:url(../images/menu_l_a.png) repeat-x top left; */}